# How to remove the url for an img tag in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to empty an img tag from it is own image but keeping the img tag empty on the page.

I use this code with no success. Any idea what is wrong here?

```
var img = $('<img id="'+ scope.elmItem +'">');
    img[0].src = '';
```

Comment: Are you not appending the created image to the DOM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combining jQuery object and pure JS properties in such manner can result in many things, most of them not working the way you want it... Try something like this:

```
$('img#'+ scope.elmItem).attr('src', '');
```

Or the pure JS approach:

```
document.getElementById(scope.elmItem).src = ''
```

Just stick to one and you'll be good to go.

Comment: You're welcome, just added the pure JS approach in case you want that as well.

Comment: @Shomz You can actually (but shouldn't in that way) mix jQuery and JS as the OP did, example: http://jsfiddle.net/FrS7X/

Comment: @ComFreek Yeah, I know, but in the end of the day you'll probably end with a headache.